# Card dealing, playing

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skspritenode

**Problem**

I've never made a card game before, and I'm having quite some difficulty at the moment.

However, I've managed to create the deck and such.

```
-(NSMutableArray *)arrayWithDeck:(id)sender
{
    [sender removeAllObjects];
    NSArray *faces = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"A",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10",@"J",@"Q",@"K", nil];
    NSArray *suits = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"h",@"d",@"c",@"s", nil];
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
        NSString *cardToAdd = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", faces[i % 13], suits[i / 13]];
        [sender addObject:cardToAdd];
    }
    return sender;
}
```

Then deal the cards to the players ( just to one player at the moment )

```
-(void) dealPlayersWithPlayers: (int) players withDealtCards: (int) dealt {
    if (players == 2){
        __block float add = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < dealt; i++) {
            add = add + ((self.frame.size.width / 100) * 10);
            NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", deck[i]];
            NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imageName ofType:@"png"];
            UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:bundle];
            SKTexture *texture = [SKTexture textureWithImage:image];
            cardDisplay = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:texture];
            cardDisplay.size = CGSizeMake(104, 144);
            cardDisplay.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
            cardDisplay.position = CGPointMake(-self.frame.size.width/2.5 + add, -218);
            cardDisplay.zPosition = 1;
            cardDisplay.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
            cardDisplay.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"card"];
            [self addChild:cardDisplay];
        }
    }
}
```

Then when touchesBegan, on a card it animates to the centre of the screen, i.e a pre-phase for a "lay cards" button. However, I'm really struggling to figure a way to keep track of the card pressed. I.e, is the card Js, Ah, 8c or whatever it could be so it can obviously be used, However the SKSpriteNode.name is already taken for the detection on touchesBegan.

Another issue I'm having is when the cards are layed. They are messing up the z-index. However, an easy fix for this could be to just keep incrementing the z-index but is it the best way of doing it? My example here shows what I'm talking about.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say the fact that you have them rendering and moving up you are off to a great start.

My recommendation though would be to look at a MVC (Model View Controller) approach to the problem. Keep the info for cards played and what the player has for cards in a separate object from your view. That way when you touch your card you can have your controller work with your model to identify it and decide what happens next. It will be very hard to manage the game if you are relaying only on the SKSpriteNode and looking at its name with no pointer to it to compare to anything.

As far as sorting your z index your model would know which card was added first in your hand and your controller can then inform the view the appropriate position and z index.

At the very least I would consider subclassing SKSpriteNode and make a CardSpriteNode at least then you don't have to look at the sprite name for touch and could just check to see if it is a CardSpriteNode.

```
if ([node isKindOfClass:[CardSpriteNode class]])
//handle touch logic if a card
```

MVC is a simple concept and I would look at some write ups on that. Everyone has a slightly different approach to what can see what, but all agree on keeping the information separate.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I'll take a read into MVC and try to do it that way.